# Understanding how forms for associated tables work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models, has-many, belongs-to

I am new to ror.This is my question.
I use generate scaffold command to create two tables section and student.the columns are
section - name:string
student - name:string section_id:integer

in model

```
section.rb

has_many :students
```

in model

```
student.rb

belongs_to :section
```

Now the student new form has two columns to be filled i.e name and section.To create a new student should I have to know the id of each section to which a student belongs to? Is there any other way to obtain a form where I enter the student name and her section?Will changing the join column to section_name in students table help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to change the associated column name in table. your model association is correct.

1) Yes you should know the id of each section to create student.
2) your form should look like

```
<%= f.collection_select(:section_id, @sections,:id,:name) %>
```

and in the create action of student controller.

```
@student = Student.new(params[:students])
@student.save
```

here @sections = Section.all

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
@section.students.create(:name => 'joe')
```

[More detailed info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form gives you :name and :section_id, you can just do this in students#create.

```
def create
  @student = Student.create(:name => params[:name], 
                            :section_id => params[:section_id])
end
```